# Does number of static pages on a web server's storage affect it's performance?

Tags: linux, windows, web-server, filesystems, web-hosting

Imagine Website A Running on server A has 100 Static Pages and Website B Running on server B has 1000000 Static Pages, Both use the same tech (Software, Hardware E.T.C.) to run.

Does Server B use more resources (Primarily Ram, CPU) other than storage when there is no traffic?

Does Server B use more resources (Primarily Ram, CPU) when Client A (website user) requests to fetch a static web page?

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. Normally disks are design to hold data efficiently, so you wouldn't expect CPU and RAM usage to grow with data on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very generic explanation because load (CPU, RAM) depend of many factors.

If there is no traffic the both servers should consume the same amount of resources (excluding disk). Of course if you have some internal operations of indexing or something similar you can expect server B to be more loaded (mainly CPU)

If there is traffic server B will use more CPU because of disk access to so many files. And server B will be slower as web. Also RAM usage **may** be bigger on B because of caching more files.